# CSS/SCSS/JS: Dynamic height fixed header

Tags: javascript, css, fixed

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/nickfindley/pen/dJqMQW

I'm looking to have the same behavior as is currently on the page, except without setting a height on the header. The header should fit whatever content is present, adjust according to window resizing, etc. It should also be covered up by the rest of the page when scrolling. The navbar sticks to the top when it gets there with some JavaScript.

```js
var pn = $(".page-nav");
pns = "page-nav-scrolled";
hdr = $(".page-header").height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
    pn.addClass(pns);
  } else {
    pn.removeClass(pns);
  }
});

$(window).on("scroll load", function() {
  pn.toggleClass(pns, $(this).scrollTop() > hdr);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10em;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em;
  z-index: -100;
}

.page-nav {
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -4em;
  z-index: 10000000;
}
.page-nav .nav-wrapper .nav-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: .584em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.page-nav .nav-wrapper .nav-brand a {
  color: yellow;
}
.page-nav .nav-wrapper .nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
.page-nav .nav-wrapper .nav-menu .nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.page-nav .nav-wrapper .nav-menu .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: yellow;
}

.page-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.page-main {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6em;
  background-color: red;
}

.nav-wrapper, .page-content {
  margin: 0 2em;
}

.header-content {
  margin: 0 6em;
}

/* https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2 */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="page-header" role="banner">

  <section class="header-content">
    <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
    <p>Praesent non hendrerit sapien.

      <p>Praesent non hendrerit sapien. Vivamus sit amet pellentesque nisl. Maecenas hendrerit elit ut mi porta, sagittis accumsan felis mollis. Fusce ut tincidunt lectus...</p>
  </section>

</header>

<nav class="page-nav" role="navigation">

  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-brand">
      <a href="/">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-item nav-active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">News</a>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<main class="page-main">
  <section class="page-content">
    <article class="entry">
      <header class="entry-header">
        <h2>Quisque a dolor vel leo porttitor luctus</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="entry-content">
        <p class="type">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Would love a pure CSS solution but I'm plenty open to JS solutions.

Comment: *Suggested question improvements:* I would recommend adding the *javascript* tag if you are open to these solutions as well, and include all relevant code within the problem statement itself (rather than an externally linked sandbox environment like CodePen), by way of embedding a code snippet, so that the issue can be easily demonstrated and reproduced (this also allows for user-friendly troubleshooting and reproduction with the "*Copy Snippet to Answer*" functionality).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Noted and edited. Thanks, I'm not a regular around here yet.

Comment: Consider calculating the height of the element in question (`.page-header`) then adding that value to the element which currently accounts for this element's height; which looks like the `body` element by way of the `padding-top` property value. e.g: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vyqpwr Notice I've used `px` unit values for the sake of brevity, it may be better to stick to absolute length unit values like this anyway. But use your own discretion there, if you want to stick with relative length values, like `em`, take a look at the link I've included pointed to a SO question addressing this.

Comment: There is also a `.resize()` method included to account for window/viewport resizing, although this is untested.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the codepen here. What I did was

- Removed the body padding
- Removed the position fixed and added relative
- Removed the fixed height

I believe this is what you wanted.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpvmxo

Just posting the changed css sections.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  //padding-top: 10em;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  //height: 20em; // not really necessary, visible portion of header is determined by body padding-top
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: Close, but I want to keep the header fixed so it looks like the page content is sliding over it.